# GDB debugger hanging on std::cout

Tags: c++, debugging

I have been coding C and C++ for a while now due to my studies. We used to use Visual Studio as an IDE during coding lessons at school.

I am now trying to learn to use GNU Compiler tools and Debugger. I am using CodeLite IDE version 9.1.8, with TDM-GCC-64 5.1.0 compiler.

My specific problem is the GDB debugger. I am somewhat familiar with its usage (Step into, Step over etc.). Everytime I try to debug ANY of my own code, the debugger stops fine at breakpoint(s) and lets me continue from there.

However, every single time I hit "cout" with the debugger, it refuses to step to the next line. When hitting some line with "cout" on it, I press "F10" to go to the next line, but the debugger will not continue from there. It always freezes, does not respond to any command, and I have to force shutdown the debugger. Every other imaginable statement is fine, but not "cout" in any form.

Those who are familiar with CodeLite probably know the green arrow at the left edge of the text editor window when debugging. When the arrow hits "cout" and I press "F10" to step to next line, the arrow flashes. When I hit "F10" again, the arrow flashes again. This can be done for about 3-4 times before the arrow disappeares completely from the left sidebar and the debugger hangs there.

[Starting debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcVX4.jpg)

[Debugger hanging and arrow disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsP5x.jpg)

Here is an example code. It is in Finnish, so you may not understand what I am trying to print, but that's not important.

The class "Henkilo" contains two private variables, string for name and int for age. Also `<<` operator is overloaded, allowing the object to be directly printed by cout.The assignment on this piece of code was to demonstrate usage of copy constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Henkilo.h"


int main()
{
    Henkilo henkilo1;

    henkilo1.setName("Jaakko");
    henkilo1.setAge(24);

    Henkilo henkilo2(henkilo1);

    std::cout << "\nLuotiin henkil\2241, jonka tiedot ovat: " << std::endl << henkilo1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Kopioitiin henkil\2241 objektiin henkil\2242. Henkil\224n 2 tiedot ovat: " << henkilo2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please forgive whatever errors I may have done posting this, this is my first time.

EDIT:

@KennyOstrom

Yes, I am able to step into the function, now that I tested it. It also seems to hang in there too.

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Henkilo& obj) 
    os << "\nNimi : " << obj.name<< std::endl << "Ik\204 : " << obj.age << std::endl; 
    return os;
}
```

It seems to hang at the line where you insert string literals to the "os" object.

EDIT:

@PaulMcKenzie

Sorry, didn't think about that point at all. Here is the implementation of the class. It is a basic class for person, with fields for name and age.

Henkilo.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Henkilo
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int age;
public:
    Henkilo();
    Henkilo(std::string initName, int initAge);
    Henkilo(const Henkilo& henkilo);
    void setName(std::string newName);
    std::string getName();
    void setAge(int newAge);
    int getAge();
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Henkilo& obj);
    ~Henkilo();

};
```

Henkilo.cpp

```
#include "Henkilo.h"

Henkilo::Henkilo() : name(""), age(0) {};
Henkilo::Henkilo(std::string initName, int initAge) : name(initName), age(initAge) {};
Henkilo::Henkilo(const Henkilo& henkilo) : name(henkilo.name), age(henkilo.age) {};

void Henkilo::setName(std::string newName) { name = newName; };
std::string Henkilo::getName() { return name; };
void Henkilo::setAge(int newAge) { age = newAge; };
int Henkilo::getAge() { return age; };

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Henkilo& obj) 
{ 
    os << "\nNimi : " << obj.name<< std::endl << "Ik\204 : " << obj.age << std::endl;
    return os;
}
Henkilo::~Henkilo() {};
```

Comment: If you only try a blank string, `std::cout << "" << std::endl;`, does it allow you to step over it? This might be a bug report in the tool, over a bug present in your code.

Comment: Nope, it still hangs. It does however print the empty string and newline after it. This problem was also an issue with Dev-C++ and Code::Blocks IDEs.

Comment: are you able to step into the function which handles operator<< for Henkilo instances?

Comment: Whoops sorry about this offtopic. Someone just edited my post and I accidentally removed the changes :D Please feel free to edit it to better form.

Comment: @JoonasOnatsu You really should post an [mcve].  You say it is the debugger, but there are unknowns in what you've posted.  The `Henkilo` class and what you're doing inside of it is unknown.  It could be corrupting memory, thus corrupting the way the output streams work.  Maybe the `operator <<` for `Henkilo` is buggy and you're in an infinite loop.  You also have this:  `Henkilo henkilo2(henkilo1);`  invoking the copy constructor, and we have no idea how that's implemented.   You should post code we all can copy / paste / run into the code editor, compile, and run the application.

Comment: @JoonasOnatsu -- If the assignment was to demonstrate the copy constructor, and you wrote a user-defined copy constructor, if you didn't write it correctly, then all bets are off.  That's why you should post your code, and not just assume that "this works, so I won't post it".

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your overload of the outputstream operator is returning anything. You have your return statement after the first line, and it has nothing after it. Try this:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Henkilo& obj) {
  os << "\nNimi : " << obj.name<< std::endl << "Ik\204 : " << obj.age << std::endl; 
  return os;
}
```

Comment: FFS. Sorry about my poor StackOverflow using skills :D The original copy-pasted piece of code was containing the correct return statement.

Comment: Was that the issue?

Comment: No, my original code is just like yours. I just happened to f*ck up the code I was pasting.